# Skipping hours in a matplotlib plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to plot the hourly variation of a quantity over a period of a week with matplotlib. I am pulling data from a mysql table which gives me the hourly timestamp and the count for the hour. The problem I am facing is that some hours have a zero count and so don't show up in the mysql query result. I want to plot the time stamp on the x axis and the count on the y axis. To fix this issue, I tried to append a "" (nothing) to the x axis array whenever that hour's value was a 0 and append the timestamp whenever its available , but it messes up the formatting of the graph. Is there a better way to handle this?

Thanks

Comment: Matlab leaves values out, if they are set to NaN. I'm not sure, if something similar works for Python. You may give it a shot.

Comment: What are the timestamps returned by your mySQL query: strings, integers, floats?  It sounds like you need to turn them into `datetime` objects before plotting them with `plt.plot(myTimestamps,myCounts)`.  Also, do you want to plot a zero count mark for the unreturned hours or leave it blank?

Comment: insert a `0` into you y-data array and the proper timestamp into the x-data if you want to show the zero points, or nothing into either array if you want to skip them.